# Unable to understand component (TasksRepositoryComponent) in android-architecture sample todo-mvp-dagger

Tags: android, mvp, dagger-2

I am trying to go through this android-architecture sample code :-
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp-dagger/todoapp

I have read this user guide as well -
https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide

This is the code in **TasksRepositoryComponent**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {TasksRepositoryModule.class, ApplicationModule.class})
public interface TasksRepositoryComponent {

    TasksRepository getTasksRepository();
}
```

ToDoApplication which extends Application has this code in onCreate() -

```
mRepositoryComponent = DaggerTasksRepositoryComponent.builder()
                .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule((getApplicationContext())))
                .build();
```

I can't understand a few things :-

1. Why doesn't TasksRepositoryComponent have an inject() method like other components in the app?
2. Why doesn't ToDoApplication also call the method tasksRepositoryModule() in DaggerTasksRepositoryComponent before build()? Why isn't that required?

Is there any place I can find a good documentation of rules to be obeyed while using dagger2?

Comment: These might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40562481/dagger-2-lack-of-constructor-injection-example/40563125#40563125 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40545075/dagger2-and-android/40546157#40546157 although there's a lot of things I don't use yet (`@IntoSet`, `@Binds`, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why doesn't `TasksRepositoryComponent` have an`inject()` method like
>   other components in the app?

`TaskRepositoryComponent` is a parent component with the sole purpose of publishing the binding for `TaskRepository` to its depedent components. The dependent components will inherit the binding for `TaskRepository` and be able to inject it into their injection sites. Have a look at the [documentation for dependent components](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Component.html#dependencies()) for more information about this feature.

> Why doesn't `ToDoApplication` also call the method
>   `tasksRepositoryModule()` in `DaggerTasksRepositoryComponent` before
>   `build()`? Why isn't that required?

`TasksRepositoryModule` has a default public constructor with no parameters so the generated component can initialize it without it being explicitly constructed in the builder. Have a look at the generated code in `DaggerTasksRepositoryComponent` - you'll see something like

```
if (tasksRepositoryModule == null) { 
    tasksRepositoryModule = new TasksRepositoryModule(); 
}
```